# Displaying Images = Int Result

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with MVC5 and I am trying to display 1 image per number in an int, for example:

If the rating is 5, show 5 stars.

I have found a way to do this but it's a real horrible work around, I would prefer to understand how to right the foreach loop on this.

CODE:

```
public class RestaurantReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }    
}
```

=========================================================

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = 
        from r in _reviews 
        orderby r.Name descending 
        select r;

    return View(model);
}
```

=========================================================

Example of Data Source:

```
static List<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantReview> _reviews = new List<RestaurantReview>
{
    new RestaurantReview {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Cinnamon Club",
        City = "London",
        Country = "UK",
        Rating = 10,
    },
```

Comment: You mean that you want display image with the rating for **every** item? If so, simply create for loop.

Comment: There's no view in the question.  How are you displaying this?  Is a simple `for` loop from 1 - Rating not working somehow?

Comment: My current view is simply: <span>Rating: @item.Rating</span>

Comment: But I don't want a static number to be displayed and would much rather the value was looped over and foreach of the numbers displayed, load the image

Answer (score 0):

you do this with CSS really,     for example.   you html may look like this:

```
foreach(var item in model.items){
   <span id="star@(item.rating)">&nbsp;</span>
   <span>@mitem.name</span>
}
```

I dont agree with this hard coded solution, but you could do this:

```
var model = 
        from r in _reviews 
        orderby r.Name descending 
        select new {   name = r.name, image = "star" + r.rating, field3 = r.blah, field4 = r.blahblah }
```

However as explained below, you change the image, you have to change the code, if you change the image location, you also have to change your code.  If you want to change the ratings.   You have to change our code.

another solution is client side:   http://wbotelhos.com/raty

or something similar.   https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+ratings&oq=jquery+ratings&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3043j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: where star10 is a css class with background image of 10 stars

Comment: Well, that's highly similar to what I already have, I thought there may have been a better way to do this.

Comment: don't see what is much better than css really, anything else would either be more serverside, or more clientside code right?? and css is always best in my opinion for styling etc.   the standard, plus if you ever have to change anything, like the images etc.   you change your css, not your code, and then have to re-publish your code.   also as a dev,   for html styled elements, i would look at css first, not in the code behind.    what if you changed images from a pnp to a jpg, or put images on a cdn  etc etc

Comment: you could on the linq select add an extra field, with your image name, but again, changes to images = changes to the code.  this is done in your select r, you would do select new { field1 = "image name" }

Comment: Ideally I wanted it to do this:

Comment: If rating is 10, display image 10 times, rather than creating 10 styles, as if the rating system ever changes to 100 or the image source changes etc then its a lot to edit

Comment: in reality would you have a rating to 100,   if the rating goes to 10, that's the best, your rating up to 100 makes no logical sense, because your not showing what the value is out of.   IE  rating 1 - 5   with a score of 3 = 3 stars bright and 2 stars faded out.  you know this is a rating,   100 stars would not be a rating, it would just be 100 stars.   besides in css you use a sprite sheet for stars etc.   think maybe you need to re-look at either the question or your whole rating system and come up with an idea that makes more sense all round.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, with this project I am being completely theoretical. It was more of a live example of how I can complete a foreach loop with the image looping over for each 1 until it increments to it's highest. It won't always be an image either, but thanks for your comments

Comment: i have updated the answer above to include an example of hard coded custom results from a query / list of results

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop would do this:

```
for (i=0; i < item.Rating; i++) {
<img src="star">
}
```